# Is possible integrate Augmented Reality and glases with ARCore?

Tags: augmented-reality, arcore, android-augmented-reality

I would like to know if is possible to develop Augmented Reality for glasses with the AR Core library by google.

Is there any documentation about it?

I need to develop an augmented reality project with glasses and I found this library(ar core), but I do not find a resource realeted with glasses, actually I don not find any information around the web.

Its dfferent AR for mobiles and glasses or it requires other techniques.

Thanks

I've already checked de ar core documentation but there is nothing

I would like to know the process of developing AR for glasses.

Comment: What do you mean by glasses? Carboard, oculus, hololens...?

Comment: No you can't. With ARCore you can only deploy your application to mobile platforms.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you can use ARCore SDK for Google smart glasses, but other glasses listed in a table have **their own development kits**. I suppose [PTC Vuforia](https://www.ptc.com/en/products/augmented-reality) must be the most robust choice for you because it supports an External Camera and a [range of Digital Eyewear](https://engine.vuforia.com/devices).

Here is a [List of the 10 best AR smart glasses](https://www.aniwaa.com/best-of/vr-ar/best-augmented-reality-smartglasses/) that you can read about:

[image]

> For each model you can get more info using `Find out more` link on that website.

**Unfortunately, there's no official Google documentation on smart glasses' integration at the moment**.

Comment: Most, if not all of those smart glasses are not supported by ARCore.

Comment: @Salbrox, sorry but I've already written it: `"...other glasses have their own development kits..."`

Comment: sorry, my bad. When you said "Google smart glasses" I thought you meant Android smart glasses. I know a lot of those glasses (if not all) listed use Android. But they are not Android certified devices and cannot use ARCore. I'd love to get my hands on a pair that ARCore supports!

Comment: I'd love too... ))